# Is it possible to Executed single WCF service hosted on two different Servers Connecting to same single DB

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am working with an Idea where I have created a `WCF service` and need to host it on two different servers with same port number and both of these WCF service is suppose to connect to same Database at back end, my question is it possible for me to execute this idea or it will create problem?

And if its possible,can anyone please guide me to helping documents or examples so that I can execute this task,

One of my confusion is, if I try to connect one table from Database(I have used Connected Architecture) via one WCF service and again there is call from another WCF service from other web server to hit same table  then definitely it will be in mess, how I am going to handle this..???

My priority is only my WCF Service should not crash..

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why two servers? Why not a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal scenario, that there are several web servers hosting WCF services Connecting to the same database.

If you have several users calling a WCF service at the same time that Connects to a database, the database does not notice that the Calls are coming from one or 2 servers (except that there is not Connection pooling across 2 servers).

What you need to be carefull With is that you Lock data when it needs to be locked, and that you do not keep the Lock longer than necessary.